# How to change order for<action method="addLinkBlock” …> in magento layout xml?

Tags: xml, templates, magento, layout

I know that for

```
<action method="addLink">
```

, we can add `<position>`as parameter to arrange link position, but in my customized top link,  the extension use addLinkBlock to add link, how can i arrange the position in this case?

Hope for reply, thanks!

```
<block type="cartview/view" name="cartview_toplink" template="cartview/toplink.phtml" >
   <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar2" as="topcart" template="cartview/sidebar.phtml"/>
</block>

<action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>cartview_toplink</blockName></action>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a `position` attribute to the block itself:

```
<block type="cartview/view" name="cartview_toplink" template="cartview/toplink.phtml" >
    <action method="setAttribute"><key>position</key><value>1000</value></action>
</block>

<action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>cartview_toplink</blockName></action>
```

---

I worked this out by inspecting the code in Magento Enterprise 1.10.1.1:

```
// Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links->addLinkBlock line 109
public function addLinkBlock($blockName)
{
    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock(ckName);
    $this->_links[$this->_getNewPosition((int)$block->getPosition())] = $block;
    return $this;
}
```

(I know this question was asked ages ago, but I hope this helps).